# Is there any way to call a class from inside subparser?

Tags: python, argparse

Inside of

```
def parse_args():
```

I have a few subparsers, I typically call functions directly

```
.set_defaults(func=SOMEFUNCTION)
```

but I do have a

```
class Something(object):
```

How can I access the class and then call the function inside? I am trying to accomplish this instead of having all the add_arguments() under **main**

Comment: "access the class and then call the function inside" is unclear. Do you want to call a method or something? Describe exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: I assume this is a follow up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315599/not-getting-namespace-returned-from-subparser-in-parse-args

Comment: It is! So close lol. I'm embarrassed at how argparse looked before. This refactor is coming along nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a lot about your needs

But you are doing something like:

```
subparser.set_defaults(func=SOMEFUNCTION)
```

and later

```
args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(args)       # call the function
```

to run `SOMEFUNCTION` on the rest of the args (or some other values).  The subparser does not run your function, it just puts that object into the namespace.  You call it after parsing.

If `SOMEFUNCTION` is a method of a class you could do something like

```
(func = Something(...).some_method)
```

The whole point to doing

```
subparse.set_defaults(func=...)
```

is to set an attribute in the args namespace to something that is useful when that subparser is used.  It doesn't have to be a function, it doesn't even have to be a callable.  It could be a string, it could be several values, it could be an instance of this class.  It could be the class.

```
subparser.set_defaults(class=SetterUpper)
...
obj = args.class()
obj.dostuff()
```

If during parsing you ask for this subparser, the main parser pass the action to `subparse`.  In other words, `subparse.parse_args(strings, namespace)`.  `subparse` then adds its defaults to `namespace`, and parses the `stings`.  So all the `set_defaults` does is add its arguments to the namespace when this particular subparse is used.  Nothing more.  Now you have one or added attributes in the `namespace` that you can use how you want.

Another thing you can do with subparsers is specify a `dest` parameter

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
```

Then `args.cmd` will be the name of subparser you invoked, e.g. `adduser`.  Then you can do

```
if args.cmd in ['adduser']:
    # perform the actions related to `adduser`
    obj = Something(...) # make instance
    obj.mymethod(...)    # run a method of this instance
```

You may have to use this approach rather than the `set_defaults` if you can't create the instance or function before parsing.

Or `SOMEFUNCTION` could be defined to create the needed instance.

```
def SOMEFUNCTION(args):
    obj = Something(args)
    obj.mymethod(...)
```

Comment: Ok this makes more sense now. I'll give this a try today. 